# I want to move the turtle in a certain path and at the same time, I want to save all the pixels it moves through in a list of variables

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to save each and every pixels the turtle moves through as it moves from say(-305,305) to (205,305).
I want to save each and every of those coordinates on the path in a variable. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Atleast you could have added a solutuion to my problem along with the advice,friend..Anyways,I had no idea that writing in UCASE is considered rude.

Answer (score 0):

I.
  You need some kind of mechanism for intervention to the drawing process,
similar to the `update` function in the `Tkinter` library and the callback functions of the `OpenGL` library.
  There is an `ontimer` function in the `Turtle` library, which can perform some action
(in your case - insertion into a list) after a given time period.

This method is shown below. It works but have some limitations:
1. it doesn't work if drawing speed is fastest ( `turtle.speed('fastest')` ),
2. it doesn't want to insert a very first pair of coordinates in a list - you have to do this insertion by yourself,
3. Some parts of a drawing may have gaps. When replaying from a list, which stores coordinates only, such situation is not processed (you will get a drawing without gaps).

```py
import turtle as tr
from turtle import *

time = 3  # 3 milliseconds period
status = False

coord=[]  # List of coordinates

sx, sy = -305, 305  # Start point
ex, ey = 205, 305   # End point

def func():  # Timer callback function
   if status:
      coord.append([tr.xcor(),tr.ycor()])  # list of lists
#      coord.append(pos())                 # list of tuples
      ontimer(func, t = time)

def redraw():  # Replay function
   tr.up()
   tr.goto(coord[0][0], coord[0][1])
   tr.down()
   for i in range(1, len(coord)):
      tr.goto(coord[i][0], coord[i][1])

def restart2():  # Keyboard callback function
   tr.reset()
   redraw()

tr.screensize(768, 512)          # Preliminary actions
tr.setup(width = 1.0, height = 1.0)
tr.onkeypress(restart2)
tr.listen()
tr.up()
tr.goto(sx,sy)

coord.append([sx, sy])    # Manual recording of the first point - list of lists case
#coord.append(tr.pos())   # list of tuples case
status = True
tr.ontimer(func, t = time)  # Start timer
tr.down()
tr.goto(ex, ey)             # Main drawing process
status = False              # "Stop" timer (timer pause for this example)

tr.up()
tr.home()
coord.append([tr.xcor(), tr.ycor()])  # Manual recording of the first point after gap
status = True
tr.ontimer(func, t = time)  #  Continue timer
tr.down()
while True:          # Examlpe from the Turtle library docs
   tr.forward(200)
   tr.left(170)
   if abs(tr.pos()) < 1:
      break

tr.home()
tr.circle(50)
tr.circle(120, 180) 
status = False  # "Stop" timer

print(coord)  # print to console
tr.done()
```

Press any key for replay path from the list.

II.
A lot of drawings have analytical solutions. It is much simpler then store a lot of coordinates.
It is probably simpler (but not faster?) to store the coordinates of the beginning and the end of drawing parts and to calculate desired intermediate points analytically.